# Want to count entire table having value of "1" in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table `feedback` having columns `ans1`,`ans2`,`ans3` ...., each column has values from 0 to 2. I want to count all columns where value is 1

In frontend I have displayed 0 as Poor, 1 as Good and 2 as Excellent. I want to count total number of Poor Feedback, Good Feedback and Excellent Feedback. for example if the table have two 0s in ans1, three 0s in ans2 so total should be five 0s.

Comment: First fix your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), you can be certain that your design is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

One option, using summation of boolean expressions:

```
SELECT
    SUM((ans1 = 0) + (ans2 = 0) + ... + (ansN = 0)) AS poor_count,
    SUM((ans1 = 1) + (ans2 = 1) + ... + (ansN = 1)) AS good_count,
    SUM((ans1 = 2) + (ans2 = 2) + ... + (ansN = 2)) AS excellent_count
FROM feedback;
```

Comment: I've done it with 
$ex    = $this->db->query("SELECT  (
                        SELECT COUNT(service_ans_1)
                                FROM   dine_in_feedback WHERE service_ans_1 = 2
                                ) AS a,
                                (
                                 SELECT COUNT(service_ans_2)
                                FROM   dine_in_feedback WHERE service_ans_2 = 2
                                ) AS b
                                (
                                 SELECT SUM(a+b)
                                    ) as ex")->row()->ex;

Answer (score 0):

maybe double looping can solve it,

```
$feedback = $this->db->get('feedback'); //get your data table
$poor = 0; $good = 0; excel=0;
foreach($feedback as $data1){
    foreach($data1 as $data2){
        if($data2 == 0){
           $poor++;
        }
        if($data2 == 1){
           $good++;
        }
        if($data2 ==2){
           $excel++;
        }
    }
```